# How to find all running Apache-related processes?

Tags: linux, apache

How to find all running Apache-related processes?

There is a vulnerability list stating that Apache 2.2.x<2.23-dev / 2.4.x<2.4.26 Multiple Vulnerabilities pub:22.06.2017

I have a suspicion that two versions of Apache are installed.It is necessary to determine where it is installed and delete the old versions, leaving only the current version.

I was trying to find out the Apache version.
Here is the result:

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built: Apr 28 2023 16:54:19

apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built: Apr 28 2023 16:54:19
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Why exactly do you think that there are several versions installed? Anyway, maybe you can do `find / -type f -executable -name "httpd" `